# How to force stop/kill Spring Redis embedded server programmatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

I am using Redis embedded server for my integrations tests and I noticed that using the `RedisServer.stop()` method is not really stoping the mock server. Any idea how to force kill it in my test cases?

Dependency:

```
        <!-- Redis test mock server  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedded-redis</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Cache integration test:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class, RestDocumentationExtension.class})
class CacheServiceImplTest {

    private RedisServer redisServer;

    @MockBean
    private StoreRepository repo;

    @Autowired
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private CacheService cacheService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
//        if (redisServer.isActive()) {
////            redisServer.stop();
//            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
//                public void run() { redisServer.stop(); }
//            });
//        }
        redisServer.start();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void preDestroy() {
//        redisServer.stop();
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> redisServer.stop()));
        redisServer.stop();
    }


    @Test
    void saveStoreToRedis() {
        List<Store> stores = new ArrayList<>();
        initializeStores(stores);
        when(repo.findAll()).thenReturn(stores);
        List<StoreResponse> actualStoresResponse = storeDao.findAll();
        Assert.assertNotNull(actualStoresResponse);
//        cacheService.invalidateCache();
    }

}
```

I am getting error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xxx.CacheServiceImplTest.ORIGINAL': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't start redis server. Check logs for details.
```

But when I kill it manually things work just fine.

```
lsof -i:6370
COMMAND     PID     USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
redis-ser 80714 XXX    4u  IPv4 0x5c18b66bd501f58d      0t0  TCP localhost:6370 (LISTEN)
  kill -9 80714
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using kotlin, but you can modify this so it works better for your test, but I'm using this and it appears to be killing the RedisServer I created

```
@AfterEach
fun killkillkill() {
    if (redisServer.isActive) {
        redisServer.stop()
    }
}
```

Note that if you stop the tests before they are complete, this appears to not be triggered